# Vue params lost in in-app browser of Instagram, Facebook, etc

Tags: facebook, vue.js, parameters, instagram

I am lately struggling with the use of the Share API in my Vue-PWA. When a user shares our App, a unique param is attached to the shared link in order to attribute the referral. Everything works fine in normal browsers, but when the link is opened through Instagram or Facebook in their in-app browser, all these information are always lost.

www.my-site.de/steve10 than always becomes www.my-site.de

Has somebody an idea of how to pass information in the sharing link?

[image]

Comment: What “referral”? I hope you are aware that you are not allowed to reward users for sharing in any way. // Are you properly setting the `org:url` meta tag to that URL including the parameter? If you just set it to the version without, then Facebook will take that as the “real” URL. (And if you include it, then Facebook will see each of those as individual Open Graph objects – so reaction and share counters will be split among them.)

Comment: @misorude thanks for your quick reply. I am not talking about posts but instead about pm messages. When using the Share API, the user can select over which medium to share the "personal message". org:url is now www.my-site.de/landing/:username but still, www.my-site.de/landing/steve is not working, the information "steve is lost"

Comment: When the same link is opened over whatsapp or short message or outlook etc..., everything is working as it should be. You think that this kind of info is not allowed in the in-app browser?

Comment: The in-app browser should not arbitrarily decide what is a “valid” link and what isn’t. Did you re-scrape your URLs, to updates Facebook’s cache, after changing the og:url? The in-app browser might still be using outdated information otherwise. (And you might have to send new messages to test, Facebook does not retroactively update shares, when the OG meta data gets changed, it might be similar for private messages.)

Comment: Thanks, I used facebook debugger for re-scraping, now og:url changed to https://www.my-site.eu/landing/:username - but unfortunately the link gets still changed to https://www.my-site.eu/landing (I always send a new link)

Comment: Can you show a real example URL?

Comment: https://www.dining4balance.eu/#landing/steve (in normal browsers, in the dialog box, you see that after 6 seconds, the username is correctly extracted as steve)

Comment: when the link is opened over your inbox in instagram, the username is not extracted as the url is "capped" after landing

Comment: I have added a picture above, so the og:url seems to be correct and up-to-date

Comment: Ah, you should have said upfront that you are talking about _that_ kind of URLs … Those are simply problematic, the fragment portion of the URL was never meant for anything but client-side use. It appears Facebook treats the hash portion differently in the in-app browser - if that is due to a technical limitation, or if they are leaving it out in the first place, when passing the data, don’t know. You can either file a bug report and ask if this is something they are willing to fix - or rewrite your system to use different URLs, that don’t try and stuff important info into the hash portion.

Comment: That would mean, using a SPA (client-side-rendering), I am not able to pass any information with the url? Hm that is said, then I have to force users to share with Whatsapp, outlook/gmail or short message using the web Share API. Thank you so much for your time and effort put in

Comment: Not with URLs containing values after the `#`. And pure client-side rendering is not suitable to provide OG meta data for different URLs in the first place - the meta tags need to be directly in the original HTML code the server returns when a specific URL is requested. Any attempts at setting them via JS on the client side are fruitless, Facebook does not care for client-side JavaScript either.